# Traversing a Binary Search Tree in Swift

Tags: tree, swift

I'm implementing the Binary Search Tree data structure in Swift. It looks like this:

```
class BinarySearchTree<Key: Comparable, Value> {

    let key: Key
    var value: Value
    var left, right: BinarySearchTree<Key, Value>?

    init(key: Key, value: Value) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }

    // irrelevant methods for constructing a tree

}
```

To be able to traverse through it using `for (key, value) in myTree { }`, `BinarySearchTree` has to implement `SequenceType`. This is my first attempt:

```
​
extension BinarySearchTree: SequenceType {

    func generate() -> AnyGenerator<(Key, Value)> {
        let leftGenerator = left?.generate()
        let rightGenerator = right?.generate()

        let (key, value) = (self.key, self.value)
        var generatedSelf = false

        return AnyGenerator {
            if generatedSelf { return rightGenerator?.next() }
            else if let next = leftGenerator?.next() { return next }
            else {
                generatedSelf = true
                return (key, value)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It works fine, but when I run benchmarks, it's just not as fast as I'd like. Can my traversal algorithm be improved, or is this the fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `generate()` method works correctly, as far as I can see. But it
creates an `AnyGenerator` for *every node* in the tree, i.e. it uses
more memory than necessary. Each call to the `next()` method of the generator
then traverses down the `next()` methods along the left or right subtrees,
which makes it slow.

An iterative approach using a stack instead of "nested generators"
seems to be faster. Here is a possible implementation of 
the **iterativeInorder** algorithm described in [Wikipedia: Tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_2):

```
func generate() -> AnyGenerator<(Key, Value)> {

    var node : BinarySearchTree? = self
    var stack : [BinarySearchTree] = []

    return AnyGenerator {
        // Traverse from current node to the far left, pushing all 
        // nodes onto the stack:
        while let node1 = node {
            stack.append(node1)
            node = node1.left
        }
        if !stack.isEmpty {
            // Pop node from stack and return its (key, value),
            // then continue with right subtree.
            let current = stack.removeLast()
            defer { node = current.right }
            return (current.key, current.value)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the size of the `stack` array is limited by the tree height.

In my test with a tree of 1,000,000 nodes, the traversal is done
in about 0.2 seconds, compared to 3.5 seconds with your original
method (test done in Release mode on a MacBook).

Comment: Thanks, your implementation is indeed a lot faster than mine. I also did some benchmarks with a tree of 1,000,000 nodes. My original method takes a little under 4 seconds, similar to your results, but traversal using your method still takes nearly a second for me, and I'm not sure why. I populate the tree with a million random values using `arc4random_uniform(1_000_000)` (though of course I didn't start measuring until after the tree was populated) - was your method any different?

Comment: @TimVermeulen: Well, I was too lazy to implement an insert method, therefore I just build a completely balanced tree, that might explain the difference.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't really expect a balanced tree to perform better in traversal...

Comment: I also implemented a red-black tree, and unfortunately, traversal was still relatively slow.

Comment: great thinking, @MartinR.  The "easy" way to traverse a tree is just recursively; I've been wondering how one could encapsulate a recursive traverse inside `IteratorProtocol` or generator.  It's kind of confusing - you'd have to have "pauses", return that one, and "continue from that point" when called again for the next one.  (A bit like programming a frame-based game engine, when you use coroutines to basically "wait" until the next frame.)

Comment: @JoeBlow: Thanks. A `yield` statement (as in Python) would make it easier :)

Comment: Right!    I also do Unity3d/c# and they use `IEnumerator` as the mechanism to step through to the next frame. (It's lovely really.)  (Me [explaining that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35280256/294884) for Unity beginners.)  Thanks again for the awesome example code.